# Java Swing JPanel Object Sizes all match JTextField size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, preferredsize

I've got an unusual issue with all of the objects inside of a JPanel taking the size of the JTextField.  Even if I try to force a size on the other objects, they still take the size specified for the textfield as their own.  For example, I'm trying to setup a single panel in its own method as follows:

```
private JPanel setupID() {
    JLabel projLbl = new JLabel("Project ID:");
    JButton verifyBtn = new JButton("Verify ID");
    projID = new JTextField(25);
    verifyBtn.setToolTipText("Verifies that the entered ID is not already in use.");
    JPanel theID = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
        theID.add(projLbl);
        theID.add(projID);
        theID.add(verifyBtn);
    return theID;
}
```

What I end up with is a window that looks like this... [image]
The `JFrame frame;` that this is being loaded into has the `frame.pack()` method called on it to auto adjust the frame size.  If I create the individual objects in a `BorderLayout()` in different areas (WEST,CENTER,EAST for example) they'll work as intended, but when they're loaded into the panel, they all size based off the `JTextField(25)`.  Any ideas why this is?

Comment: This is the behavior of GridLayout. If you want more control over the sizes of each component in your GUI, you need to choose a different LayoutManager. For a quick look at the differences between the standard LayoutManagers, check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: @Code-Guru You seriously need to make that an answer and add an example!

Comment: Thanks for the Link Code-Guru, that helps a lot with describing the different layout types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Code-Guru and asemax has pointed out.  It would appear that you are using a `GridLayout`, which is designed to layout components in a grid, evenly, using the available space.

Try using something like a `GridBagLayout` instead...

[image]

```
public class BadLayout08 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadLayout08();
    }

    public BadLayout08() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Project ID:"));
            add(new JTextField(25));
            add(new JButton("Verify ID"));
        }

    }

}
```

You may find [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) of some use when you need to decide on which layout to use.

Comment: That did it.  I guess I need to spend a little more time looking at the different layouts.  I'm still trying to learn java, swing, and AWS API all while creating programs for work. The plan is to create crude, working versions now, then go back and refine/optimize the code once I've learned how to **properly** write the program in question.  Ahh the joys of learning on the job without training...  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from Java's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html):

> The GridLayout class is a layout manager that lays out a container's components in a rectangular grid. The container is divided into **equal-sized rectangles**, and one component is placed in each rectangle [...]

My guess is that the rectangle size is based on the biggest component's prefered size.
You should use an alternative layout, maybe a [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) is better suited for your needs.